# How to use File.walk in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I’m trying to walk into folder using `file.walk` this way:

```
File.walk(FileWalkDirection.BOTTOM_UP).forEach()
```

The documentation says:

> enum entry BOTTOM_UP defined in kotlin.io.FileWalkDirection
>
> Depth-first search, directory is visited AFTER its files
>
> Enum constant ordinal: 1

If I use `FileWalkDirection.BOTTOM_UP` it’s my print walk

```
emergency-support/digital/beginner/.category.yml
emergency-support/digital/.category.yml
emergency-support/physical/beginner/.category.yml
emergency-support/physical/.category.yml
emergency-support/.category.yml
```

I want to walk for this result:

```
emergency-support/.category.yml
emergency-support/physical/.category.yml
emergency-support/physical/beginner/.category.yml
emergency-support/digital/.category.yml
emergency-support/digital/beginner/.category.yml
```

How can I walk visiting files before directory?

Comment: tried TOP_DOWN?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, its always going to a directory first.

Comment: Collect the walk result into a list, then call `reversed` on it?

Comment: @jingx yeah... this is my last option :P if I don't get a better idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have to admit that I did not totally undersand your question.
If all you want is to print the files first and than the directories and you don't have any other concern you can use the 'sortedBy' function:

```
File
    .walk(FileWalkDirection.BOTTOM_UP)
    .sortedBy { it.isDirectory }
    .forEach { println(it) }
```